# How to display the output panel in Sublime Text

Tags: ide, window, sublimetext, text-editor

In Sublime Text 2, I'm running a Python script (for loop) continuously print out some results in the output panel.

I accidentally pressed the search shortcut (Ctrl + f) and the search panel appeared. The output panel disappeared.

Is there a way to call back (great to have the printed out contents) the output panel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Sublime 2, in order to call up the build results window you can use the `Tools > Build Results > Show Build Results` menu item.

If you're using Sublime 3, the same menu item exists but is also bound to a key as well (check the menu item to see what it is for your platform), and you can click on the panel chooser icon in the bottom left of the window to open a menu that displays all panels and choose the output panel from there.

If you're using one of the beta builds for Sublime 4, the same options exist as for Sublime 3 but you have to right click on the panel chooser icon to open the panel menu, as a left click instead toggles the state of the side bar.

Regardless of the version of Sublime that you're using, the build results can only be displayed in a window where at least one build has been performed (each window has its own panel). For Sublime 3 and 4 that means that the panel won't appear in the panel chooser for windows that haven't completed a build yet.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you for the superb answer. that's very professional!

Comment: @OdatNurd (a.k.a. TheSublimeTextGuru ;)) is there a way to show the Build Results as a full-size panel? (i.e. taking 100% of the Sublime Text window)

Comment: @Basj standard build systems use the `exec` command, which only displays its output into a panel; panels can be resized upwards, but only to about 3/4 of the window height. However it's possible for a build to use a custom `target` which changes the command used, and that command can display build output in a `view` instead. The prime example of that is using the `Terminus` package to run your build (see: https://youtu.be/etIJMVIvVgg) though that package is ST3 and up only. For ST2, SublimeREPL is the way to go for that.

Answer (score 4):

I use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for this, to avoid to have to open the menu *Tools > Build Results > Show Build results* each time.

For this, just add the following line in your `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+r"], "command": "show_panel",  "args": { "panel": "output.exec" } },
```